# The text of my java program is blurred depending on the Windows scale

Tags: java

I have one PC with a 100% scale and a laptop with 150% scale. The problem is that with a 100% scale the program shows the text (in my case, the numbers) perfectly but in a 150% scale the text is blurred. I'm using swing to do the program. Both of them are in Windows 10 and the jdk is 1.8.0_251.

The question is: how can I do to see the program on my laptop as I see it on my PC?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: that's right, now yes